# How to Search a File through all the SubDirectories in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have implemented this code in Delphi, it will search for the File or the name given but it omits searching all the subdirectories. How can this be done?

Code:

```
 if FindFirst(filePath,faAnyFile,searchResult)=0 then
  try
    repeat
    lbSearchResult.Items.Append(searchResult.Name);

    until FindNext(searchResult)<>0
  except
  on e:Exception do
  ShowMessage(e.Message);
  end; //try ends
  FindClose(searchResult);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't need threading, the simplest way is this:

```
procedure TForm1.AddAllFilesInDir(const Dir: string);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Dir) + '*.*', faAnyFile or faDirectory, SR) = 0 then
    try
      repeat
        if (SR.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then
          ListBox1.Items.Add(SR.Name)
        else if (SR.Name <> '.') and (SR.Name <> '..') then
          AddAllFilesInDir(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Dir) + SR.Name);  // recursive call!
      until FindNext(Sr) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(SR);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  AddAllFilesInDir('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\Aweb');
  ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: Notice in particular two important things: The `FindClose` function is called from a `finally` section, and all calls to `Items.Add` are located between `Items.BeginUpdate` and `Items.EndUpdate`.

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach uses recursion. This wouldn't be obvious to someone asking this question, if they didn't already have recursion in mind.  I'll add a comment to the code, point this out.

Comment: Can u explain the code, little things like why FindFirst(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Dir) + '*.*' and if (SR.Attr and faDirectory) = 0?

Comment: @sunandan: (1) `IncludeTrailingBackslash` is just a function that adds a \ character to the end of a string if it doesn't already end with such a character. What if `Dir` is `C:\Users`? Then we would search for `C:\Users*.*` which doesn't work, but with the aid of `IncludeTrailingBackslash`, we will instead search for `C:\Users\*.*` which does work. (2) `SR.Attr` is a bitfield, that is, a binary number in which every digit is either 1 or 0 which tells you something interesting. The fifth digit from the right is 0 or 1 depending on if the found file is a...

Comment: directory or not. `faDirectory` is `10000` in binary. Thus `SR.Attr and faDirectory` is non-zero if and only if the found file is a directory. Hence, `if (SR.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then` should be read as 'if the found file is not a directory', and in such a case, we add the file to the list box. On the other hand, if the file is a directory (but not the directory '..' or '.' that exist in (almost) every directory and simply means the previous and the current directory, respectively), we call the function `AddAllFilesInDir` again with this new directory.

Answer (score 28):

With Delphi XE and up, you can have a look at IOUtils.pas:

```
TDirectory.GetFiles('C:\', '*.dll', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
```

Comment: I used Delphi 2009 for many years. When I upgraded to XE2 and then to XE8, didn't realize these were added. +1

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is:

```
uses
  DSiWin32;

DSiEnumFilesToStringList('c:\somefolder\file.name', 0, ListBox1.Items, true, true);
```

[DSiWin32](http://17slon.com/gp/gp/dsiwin32.htm) is a free Delphi library.

Comment: Otherwise, you should start using it :)

Answer (score 1):

When i need to do `tricks`like override protected methods i tend to use a generic solution to the problem... i do a hack to the class.

Here is how to do it with `TDirectoryListbox`.

On every Form you need to use this `hacked` `TDirectoryListbox` just add `unitTDirectoryListbox_WithHiddenAndSystemFolders` to interface `uses`, that way the form will use the `hacked` `TDirectoryListbox`.

Create a file called `unitTDirectoryListbox_WithHiddenAndSystemFolders.pas` on your proyect folder.

Put this text inside that file (i will explain later what i have done):

```
unit unitTDirectoryListbox_WithHiddenAndSystemFolders;

interface

uses
    Windows
   ,SysUtils
   ,Classes
   ,FileCtrl
   ;

type TDirectoryListbox=class(FileCtrl.TDirectoryListbox)
   private
     FPreserveCase:Boolean;
     FCaseSensitive:Boolean;
   protected
     function ReadDirectoryNames(const ParentDirectory:String;DirectoryList:TStringList):Integer;
     procedure BuildList;override;
   public
     constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);override;
     destructor Destroy;override;
     property PreserveCase:Boolean read FPreserveCase;
     property CaseSensitive:Boolean read FCaseSensitive;
end;

implementation

constructor TDirectoryListbox.Create(AOwner:TComponent);
begin
     inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

destructor TDirectoryListbox.Destroy;
begin
     inherited Destroy;
end;

function TDirectoryListbox.ReadDirectoryNames(const ParentDirectory:String;DirectoryList:TStringList):Integer;
var
  TheCount,Status:Integer;
  SearchRec:TSearchRec;
begin
     TheCount:=0;
     Status:=FindFirst(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ParentDirectory)+'*.*',faDirectory or faHidden or faSysFile,SearchRec);
     try
        while 0=Status
        do begin
                if faDirectory=(faDirectory and SearchRec.Attr) 
                then begin
                          if   ('.'<>SearchRec.Name)
                            and
                               ('..'<>SearchRec.Name)
                          then begin
                                    DirectoryList.Add(SearchRec.Name);
                                    Inc(TheCount);
                               end;
                     end;
                Status:=FindNext(SearchRec);
           end;
     finally
            FindClose(SearchRec);
     end;
     ReadDirectoryNames:=TheCount;
end;

procedure TDirectoryListBox.BuildList;
var
  TempPath: string;
  DirName: string;
  IndentLevel, BackSlashPos: Integer;
  VolFlags: DWORD;
  I: Integer;
  Siblings: TStringList;
  NewSelect: Integer;
  Root: string;
begin
  try
    Items.BeginUpdate;
    Items.Clear;
    IndentLevel := 0;
    Root := ExtractFileDrive(Directory)+'\';
    GetVolumeInformation(PChar(Root), nil, 0, nil, DWORD(i), VolFlags, nil, 0);
    FPreserveCase := VolFlags and (FS_CASE_IS_PRESERVED or FS_CASE_SENSITIVE) <> 0;
    FCaseSensitive := (VolFlags and FS_CASE_SENSITIVE) <> 0;
    if (Length(Root) >= 2) and (Root[2] = '\') then
    begin
      Items.AddObject(Root, OpenedBMP);
      Inc(IndentLevel);
      TempPath := Copy(Directory, Length(Root)+1, Length(Directory));
    end
    else
      TempPath := Directory;
    if (Length(TempPath) > 0) then
    begin
      if AnsiLastChar(TempPath)^ <> '\' then
      begin
        BackSlashPos := AnsiPos('\', TempPath);
        while BackSlashPos <> 0 do
        begin
          DirName := Copy(TempPath, 1, BackSlashPos - 1);
          if IndentLevel = 0 then DirName := DirName + '\';
          Delete(TempPath, 1, BackSlashPos);
          Items.AddObject(DirName, OpenedBMP);
          Inc(IndentLevel);
          BackSlashPos := AnsiPos('\', TempPath);
        end;
      end;
      Items.AddObject(TempPath, CurrentBMP);
    end;
    NewSelect := Items.Count - 1;
    Siblings := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Siblings.Sorted := True;
        { read all the dir names into Siblings }
      ReadDirectoryNames(Directory, Siblings);
      for i := 0 to Siblings.Count - 1 do
        Items.AddObject(Siblings[i], ClosedBMP);
    finally
      Siblings.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
  if HandleAllocated then
    ItemIndex := NewSelect;
end;

end.
```

Now i explain what i have done:

- By adding `unitTDirectoryListbox_WithHiddenAndSystemFolders` to interface `uses` i make the form to use the modified (aka, `hacked`) component.
- I started by copying protected method called `ReadDirectoryNames` (the one that needs a modification), i copy it from unit `FileCtrl` and then i edit that copy on my own unit to `fix` the problem (not showing Hidden folders, neither System folders); the `trick` is to edit the call to `FindFirst` by adding after `faDirectory` the part `or faHidden or faSysFile`, i also change `SlashSep` to `IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter` (avoid some extra references, etc) and also do a reformat (indexing, etc) so i can see that method is the one i had modified.
- Then i follow things missing... like `BuildList`, that one i just simply copy it from unit `FileCtrl` without any modification (if not copied the `hack` does not work, since the call to `ReadDirectoryNames` is inside `BuildList`).
- Then i copy the declaration of `FPreserveCase` and `FCaseSensitive` and their property declarations (they are used inside `BuildList` method).
- That is it, now the modified `TDirectoryListBox` will see hidden and system folders

Hope this helps others, this way you can have both `TDirectoryListBox` (original one and modified one) at same time (but not on same form, sorry) on your project, without modifing VCL at all.

P.D.: Someone with extra knowledge maybe is able to add properties to configure if it must show or not hidden and/or system folders as an improvement, it must not be very difficoult, two private boolean variables and their corresponding `property` declaration with read and write methods... i did not do it since i would like to add not only such two, also SymLinks, etc (search for `faSymLink` on unit `SysUtils` and see how many there are, a lot of work to add them all), sorry for any inconvenience for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're answering, but it isn't this one, which asks nothing about TDirectoryListBox or modifying component methods or properties, and nothing about hidden or system files. This one asks about iterating files in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this solution for a different question a short while ago:

[Delphi: Copy Files from folder with Overall progress. CopyFileEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354033/delphi-copy-files-from-folder-with-overall-progress-copyfileex/6361275#6361275)