# How can I find the drive letters for all disks on a system?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I want to search for a file on all disks on the system. I already know how to search on a single disk from this question: [How to Search a File through all the SubDirectories in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546105/how-to-search-a-file-through-all-the-subdirectories-in-delphi)

I use it as

```
function TMyForm.FileSearch(const dirName: string);

...

FileSearch('C:');
```

What I do not know how to do is use it to find files on all available drive letters, C, D, E etc. How can I find a list of those available drive letters?

Comment: What did you try, beside finding this code?

Comment: You need to first get a list of all disks, then iterate through that list. Surely you're not the first person to do this...

Comment: Also, your code appears to search the `Windows` directory. Do you really have a `Windows` directory on every disk? Is that really what you wish to search?

Comment: Use [`FindFirstVolume`, `FindNextVolume` and `FindCloseVolume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in an outer loop. They work similarly to `FindNextFile` and friends.

Comment: The initial question was confusing to me also. I don't think OP's **code** is relevant here. OP might mention that he already knows how to search for files in single drive and has a function for it. but needs to to search all system drives.

Comment: @kobik: Although I don't find it confusing at all, I agree that the entire code may not be necessary. Just the declaration and a short description of what it does.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, exactly. if OP would have wrote a single line e.g. `FileSearch('C:\');` (not 'c:\windows') it would have been more than enough. the code itself has no use to anyone specially since it's a copy/paste from the question he linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6546819/937125

Comment: I think that at least the delaration of the function and how he uses it makes the question and the answer more useful, because people don't have to follow the link to understand it.

Comment: @Rudy You changed a lot more than that. I wrote *What I do not know how to do is find a list of all available drive letters, C, D, E etc. How can I do that?* You replaced that with *What I do not know how to do is use it to find files on all available drive letters, C, D, E etc. How can I do that?* Which is a significant change because it does not make it clear that the drive letters are not known. I didn't think my version was hard to understand, and I don't think it is important to see the function declaration. But it doesn't hurt much to include it, so long as the main point is retained.

Comment: I think it is and was perfectly clear that OP didn't know how to obtain such a list. Hence my comment and hence Ken's answer.

Comment: @David: Does your objection have anything to do with the fact that you wrote the function he posted?

Comment: No that has nothing to do with it. I made my views clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just get a list of available drives, and loop through them calling your function.

In recent versions of Delphi you can use [IOUtils.TDirectory.GetLogicalDrives](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory) to retrieve a list of all drive letters easily.

```
uses
  System.Types, System.IOUtils;

var
  Drives: TStringDynArray;
  Drive: string
begin
  Drives := TDirectory.GetLogicalDrives;
  for s in Drives do
    FileSearch(s);        
end;
```

For older versions of Delphi that don't contain IOUtils, you can use the WinAPI function [GetLogicalDriveStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx). It's considerably more complicated to use, but here's some code that wraps it for you. (You'll need Windows, SysUtils, and Types in your uses clause.)

```
function GetLogicalDrives: TStringDynArray;
var
  Buff: String;
  BuffLen: Integer;
  ptr: PChar;
  Ret: Integer;
  nDrives: Integer;
begin
  BuffLen := 20;  // Allow for A:\#0B:\#0C:\#0D:\#0#0 initially
  SetLength(Buff, BuffLen);
  Ret := GetLogicalDriveStrings(BuffLen, PChar(Buff));

  if Ret > BuffLen then
  begin
    // Not enough memory allocated. Result has buffer size needed.
    // Allocate more space and ask again for list.
    BuffLen := Ret;
    SetLength(Buff, BuffLen);
    Ret := GetLogicalDriveStrings(BuffLen, PChar(Buff));
  end;

  // If we've failed at this point, there's nothing we can do. Calling code
  // should call GetLastError() to find out why it failed.
  if Ret = 0 then
    Exit;

  SetLength(Result, 26);  // There can't be more than 26 drives (A..Z). We'll adjust later.
  nDrives := -1;
  ptr := PChar(Buff);
  while StrLen(ptr) > 0 do
  begin
    Inc(nDrives);
    Result[nDrives] := String(ptr);
    ptr := StrEnd(ptr);
    Inc(ptr);
  end;
  SetLength(Result, nDrives + 1);
end;
```

Comment: But keep in mind that there may be volumes that don't have drive letters assigned.  (In most cases it is OK to ignore them.)

Comment: @Harry: True, but the question specifically asks for the drive letters for all disks.