# Access violation while using "record" type in delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

What I need to do is read table details from **excel** file and want to create **.pas** file from it.

For the read-write purpose, I've used **record** type in **delphi 7**.

Here is the code what I've tried till now:

```
unit fImportFile;
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    tSourceFile: TEdit;
    dlgSourceFile: TOpenDialog;
    btnImport: TButton;
    procedure tSourceFileClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnImportClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TTableDetails = record
    fTableName: String;
  end;

  TFieldDetails = record
    fFieldName: String;
    fType: String;
    fShortAlias: String;
    fLongAlias: String;
    fDomainName: String;
    fFieldAttributes:TStringList;
    fComments: String;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses ComObj, uFileGeneration;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.tSourceFileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with dlgSourceFile do
  begin
    FileName := tSourceFile.Text;
    if ExtractFilePath(FileName) <> '' then
      InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(FileName);
    if Execute then
      if FileName <> '' then
        tSourceFile.Text := FileName;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.btnImportClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  cEndOfTables = '';
  cTable = 'Table';
  cTableCell = 2;
  cTableNameCell = 3; // TableNameField
  cFieldName = 'Field Name';
var
  Excel: OleVariant;
  iRow: Integer;
  aTableDetails: TTableDetails;
  aFieldDetails: Array of TFieldDetails;
  fieldCount: Integer;
  iTableName, FldWithChar, FldWithoutChar: String;
  FldList, WordList: TStringList;
  FieldName: String;
begin
  FldList := nil;
  WordList := nil;

  try
    Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    Excel.Visible := False;
    Excel.Workbooks.Open(tSourceFile.Text);
    iRow := 1;

    while (Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableCell].Value <> '') do //To exit loop when the excel record will read blank TableName
    begin
      if (Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableCell].Value = cTable) then
      begin
        iTableName := Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableNameCell].Value;
        if (iTableName = '') then
        begin
          ShowMessage('Table Name cannot be blank.');
          exit;
        end;
        aTableDetails.fTableName := iTableName;
        Inc(iRow);

        fieldCount := 0;
        FldList := TStringList.Create;
        WordList := TStringList.Create;
        ShowMessage('1 -- iRow --> ' + IntToStr(iRow));

        while (Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableCell].Value <> '') AND
          (Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableCell].Value <> cTable) do //Will create record until another table will found
        begin
          ShowMessage('2 -- Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableNameCell].Value = ' + Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableNameCell].Value);
          FieldName := Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableNameCell].Value;
          aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fFieldName := FieldName; //ERROR LINE

          ShowMessage('3 -- iRow --> ' + IntToStr(iRow));
          FldWithChar := aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fFieldName;
          FldWithoutChar := NameWithoutAnyChar(FldWithChar, WordList);
          FldList.Add(FldWithChar + '=' + FldWithoutChar);
          WordList.Clear;
          ShowMessage('4 -- iRow --> ' + IntToStr(iRow));

          if (aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fFieldName = '') then
          begin
            ShowMessage('Field Name cannot be blank. TableName: '+iTableName);
            exit;
          end;
          aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fType := Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,3].Value;
          aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fShortAlias := Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,4].Value;
          aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fLongAlias := Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,5].Value;
          aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fDomainName := Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,6].Value;
          aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fFieldAttributes.CommaText := Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,7].Value;
          aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fComments := Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,8].Value;
          Inc(fieldCount);
          Inc(iRow);
        end;
        //Once new table row will be fouund it will call below method to create a dataview file for current table
        ShowMessage('5 -- iRow --> ' + IntToStr(iRow));
        GenerateDataviewFiles(aTableDetails, aFieldDetails, FldList, fieldCount-1);
        ShowMessage('6 -- iRow --> ' + IntToStr(iRow));
      end; //End of If condition
    end; //End of outer most while loop
  finally
    FreeAndNil(WordList);
    FreeAndNil(FldList);
    Excel.Workbooks.Close;
    Excel.Quit;
    Excel := Unassigned;
  end;
end;
end.
```

I've commented **//ERROR LINE** where I'm getting error for access violation.

What I'm doing here is, creating **array of TFieldDetails** and wanted to loop through it in another file.

Please help me through this as I am a new to delphi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access an index of `aFieldDetails` which is out of bounds. You should set length of a dynamic array before that. Like this:

```
...
SetLength(aFieldDetails, fieldCount+1);
aFieldDetails[fieldCount].fFieldName := FieldName; //ERROR LINE
...
```

However, this has a poor performance unless you know how many total fields you have since the beginning. It's because everytime `SetLength` gets called, another block of memory is allocated and the whole array is copied to it.

I suggest you to use `TList` which tries to keep performance in a good shape even if you don't know how many items are gonna be added to your list.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. But one lame question here, as we are using `SetLength(aFieldDetails, fieldCount+1);` in while loop, won't it cost execution time? As we are setting length each time we are assigning field details.

Comment: @user3085495: Yes, it can slow performance (and sometimes result in memory fragmentation). The alternative is to pre-allocate the array to a number higher than you'll need, keep track of the number of elements you actually use, and then `SetLength` at the end to the number of used elements. You can see an example of doing so in the second code block [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39207791/62576); look toward the bottom where you see `SetLength(Result, 26)`. (It's a trivial example, because allocating 26 elements is not enough to affect performance, but it's an example.)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to initialize dynamic array `aFieldDetails`. Thus, its length is still zero when you try to write to it with an index `fieldCount`.

If you know the total count of fields, you should preallocate the full array by calling

```
SetLength(aFieldDetails, TheTotalFieldCount);
```

If you don't know the total count beforehand, you may use a list or another dynamic data structure, because reallocating every time you add an item is very expensive in terms of performance.

```
aFieldDetailList := TList.Create;
try
  while (Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableCell].Value <> '') AND
        (Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[iRow,cTableCell].Value <> cTable) do //Will create record until another table will found
  begin
    New(aFieldDetail); // create a new instance of aFieldDetail; aFieldDetail is of pointer type "^TFieldDetails"

    // do your loop work
  end;
  // do your after-loop work
finally
  // free all allocated memory
  for aFieldDetail in aFieldDetailList do
    Dispose(aFieldDetail);
  FreeAndNil(aFieldDetailList);
end;
```