# File search in Delphi is ignoring some Windows directories

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I'm using this code from this thread ([How to Search a File through all the SubDirectories in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546105/how-to-search-a-file-through-all-the-subdirectories-in-delphi)) to find files recursively:

```
procedure FindFilePattern(root:String;pattern:String);
var
  SR:TSearchRec;
begin
  root:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(root);
  if FindFirst(root+'*.*',faAnyFile,SR) = 0 then
  begin
      repeat
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) = SR.Attr ) and (pos('.',SR.Name)=0) then
             FindFilePattern(root+SR.Name,pattern)
          else
          begin
           if pos(pattern,SR.Name)>0 then Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(Root+SR.Name);
          end;
      until FindNext(SR)<>0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FindFilePattern('C:\','.exe');
end;
```

It's working but for some reason it's ignoring the directories Program Files, Program Files (x86) and Users. Unfortunatelly, the files I'm searching are in those folders. Does anybody know why it's happening?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks

Comment: What you say does not seem plausible. Your code won't skip program files folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Jerry Dodge mentioned, security rights is certainly one thing you *might* need to account for.  Your code *may* need to be run as an admin in order to access various system directories, and directories belonging to other users.  For the most part, simply enumerating the directories you have mentioned does not require elevated rights.  But if you find that you encounter directories that do, you can either:

1. add a UAC manifest to your app that requests elevation
2. move your enumeration code into a separate process or COM object that you can then run elevated from an un-elevated process when needed.

But aside from that, the `FindFilePattern()` procedure you copied is also implemented wrong to begin with.  It is:

1. comparing file attributes incorrectly. The expression `(SR.Attr and faDirectory) = SR.Attr )` will be true if the entry is a file, or is a directory with *NO ATTRIBUTES* on it.  It is not uncommon to encounter directories with attributes, such as system, compressed, indexed, etc.
2. comparing file names incorrectly.  The expression `(pos('.',SR.Name)=0)` will be true for all files and directories that do not contain a `.` character at all. Almost all files have a `.`, and even directories can have a `.` as  well. When handling directories, you need to ignore **only** the special `.` and `..` directory entries specifically, not any entry that has a `.` in it.
3. Worse, the combination of #1 and #2 acting together is allowing directories that have attributes, and directories that contain `.`, to be treated as files instead of as directories.  The code is not handling directories correctly in general, let alone recursively.
4. leaking all of the search handles.  `FindClose()` must be called if `FindFirst()` is successful, regardless of `FindNext()`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
uses
  SysUtils, Masks;

procedure FindFilePattern(root: String; pattern: String);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  root := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(root);
  if FindFirst(root + '*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  try
    repeat
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      if (SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
      begin
        if (SR.Name <> '.') and (Sr.Name <> '..') then
          FindFilePattern(root + SR.Name, pattern);
      end else
      begin
        if MatchesMask(SR.Name, pattern) then
          Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(Root + SR.Name);
      end;
    until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
  finally
    FindClose(SR);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FindFilePattern('C:\', '*.exe');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked liked a charm :)

Comment: Something to add: Use of `Application.ProcessMessages` is a cheap trick to avoid blocking UI, but it should come with a warning label. It creates a hidden risk of re-entrant code that the caller would not be aware of. In this particular case the effect is probably just a benign peculiarity in the output to `ListBox1`; and easily resolved by adding a re-entrancy guard. However, in general it's better to do heavy processing in a separate thread. This is more explicit, and has the added benefit that that code is "guided" to a better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs to be running with elevated privileges in order for it to access some subdirectories within the ones you speak of. As a temporary test, run "As Administrator" to verify this. If this is indeed your case, then you should add a manifest to require elevation upon startup.

Later versions of Delphi have this built-in. Under Project Options, go to the "Application" page, and check "Enable Administrator Privileges". Of course, this is the quick and easy way with the IDE, and you should instead consider writing your own custom manifest, especially if you're running an older version of Delphi which doesn't have this option.

Comment: This is true for directories that the calling user does not access to, like system directories and directories belonging to other users.  It is not true for all directories in general. Chances are, the enumeration will be able to have read-only access to a good majority of directories.

Comment: @Remy OP said "Program Files, Program Files (x86) and Users" are the ones they're trying to search.

Comment: Except that you don't actually need to run elevated just to enumerate most sections of `Program Files` and `Users`.  I just tried it and it worked fine without elevation.

Comment: @Remy Key word "most" - we don't know precisely which parts OP is expecting to work. But those directories raise a big red flag.

Comment: There are no read restrictions on Program Files (either version). There are *write* restrictions that may require elevated privileges, but anyone can read from those folders. You can always read and write to your own user folder, too, as well as the public documents tree.

Comment: I'm on a domain network, which has permissions quite strictly locked down. Now the PF directories may be readable, but certainly some users cannot see other users' files. Do we actually know anything about the OP's environment? Do we know anything about which particular subdirectories OP was unable to access? No, so it's all speculation of possible situations.